# Will migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error: overwrite an existing target store?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an existing iOS 7 app that uses core data (sqlite) locally.

I am considering adding iCloud support and have been looking at how to migrate local data to iCloud.

The `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` method `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` appears to do what I am after, but having read the documentation I am still unclear on what will happen to the *target* persistent store if it already exists before the method is called.

If store B already contains data, and I migrate store A to store B, will the original store B data be overwritten (so it now only contains data from store A), or will the method append/add the data from store A to the existing data from store B?